# How sum in excel only for given value

Tags: excel

I have in excel something like:

```
    A            B
1   Value1      10
2   Value2      20
3   Value1       5  
4   Value1      10
5   Value2      15
```

How I can sum for given value in A? For example, having something like this:

```
6        C       D
7   Value1      25  (sum of b1+b3+b4)
8   Value2      35  (sum of b2+b5)
```

Of course, how can I do this automatically and not manually.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Consider using a pivot table

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a list of the *unique* values in column `A` listed in column `C`, i.e.:

```
Row A       B   C     
1   Value1  10  Value1  
2   Value2  20  Value2
3   Value1  5           
4   Value1  10          
5   Value2  15
```

In column `D`, the following formula will count the occurences of each value in column `C`:

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A$6, "=" & $C2, B$2:B$6)
```

This should be pasted into `D2` and then copied to `D3`, `D4`, etc.

The result will look like:

```
Row A       B   C       D
1   Value1  10  Value1  25
2   Value2  20  Value2  35
3   Value1  5           
4   Value1  10          
5   Value2  15
```

**How does this work?** `SUMIF` allows criteria to be used, and if satisfied, a `SUM` of the cells is taken.  In this case, the `SUMIF` does this:

- Looks in cell range `A$2:A$6`
- Compares the value in each cell to see if it is equal to `$C2` (or `$C3`, etc dependent upon which row is being calculated)
- If it is equal, sum the value from the cell range `B$2:B$6`

**Limitations**

In order for this to work, the unique values in column `A` must already be known and listed in column `C`.  There are some ways of generating a list of unique values but they are not straight-forward.  Roll on `UNIQUE` which ships with the new version of Office.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this:

- Use a pivot table (as already mentioned in the comments).
- Use a `SumIf()` worksheet function (as mentioned in another answer). This, however, will only work if you know all names (like `Value1`, `Value2`, ... (the list MUST be limited))
- Use subtotals. This, however, will only work when you sort first.
- Write a VBA macro.